# Strict inequality for Fatou's lemma

Tags: measure-theory

I'm interested in knowing whether there is a condition for general measure spaces under which we know that we can only achieve the strict inequality of Fatou's lemma. I am working in the situation that $f_n \rightarrow f$, and the limit  of the integrals do exist so that Fatou's lemma says
$$ \int f \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \;. $$
Is there a condition on $f_n$ and $f$ which ensures
$$ \int f < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n \;. $$

Comment: A standard example in the real, Lebesgue sense occurs when the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is 0 but not uniformly so, and each $|f_n|$ is positive on a set of measure greater than zero.  Consider $f_n(x)$ = {n for 0 $\leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$; 0 o.w. }.  Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, but its integral from 0 to 1 is always 1.  This might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: For measure spaces with total mass finite, look up "uniform integrability."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice discussion of this point in *ANALYSIS* by Lieb & Loss (section 1.9 of the second edition): It $f_n$ are non-negative and converge a.e. to $f$, then
$$
\liminf_n\int f_n = \int f +\liminf_n\int|f-f_n|
$$
provided $\sup_n\int f_n<\infty$.